# What and when do I have to disclose, if I use open source software for a totally different use?

Tags: open-source, licensing

If I make a (web-based if it matters) game and have the inventory portion of it from an open source inventory program, what do I disclose?

I would say part X came from open source, or I just "hacked" then inventory system and put my game as a front end.

I just don't know where I put that on my website, or do I wait until someone asks? Does this mean my part of the software is also open source? What am I supposed to do?

I'm not sure how to ask it. I want to do the right thing and all.

Comment: T depends entirely on the terms of the license of the open source software. Consult a lawyer. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the license that the open source inventory program is under. Have you looked into that yet?

This is a good place to start for comparisons:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_licenses

Comment: no.  THanks though.  I'll make sure to compare them.

Comment: If you find out what license it's under, you can update your question, and we can help you out. Sometimes the license is in a `README` file or in something like `License.txt`. What project is it?

Answer (score 0):

You have not asked much specific with your question. The general answer is: It depends.

On what does it depend you might then ask yourself. It depends on the usage terms of the software you make use of.

You only have shared so far that the software is "open source". That term does not say much. It could mean you refer to an OSI certified Opensource<sup>tm</sup> license, however, you wrote "open source" which might be a different term. Probably you have picked something from github (compare: [Can I use the code in a Github project which does not have a license specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5521080/367456)) ?

So unless you do not share which kind of license that is you talk about not much could be said:

- If it is a permissive Free Software license, your code can normally stay under it's own license.
- If it is a copyleft Free Software license, your code normally is being licensed under the same license.
- If it is a compromise license, it depends on the type of work and way of interaction / derivation / usage / packaging.

In any case it always depends on

1. the concrete licenses for all works in question.
2. the concrete type of work and way of combining it with your work.
3. if you plan to go conform with the licensing or you want to exploit it.

You have not specified much of both, so no better suggestion can be given. Also take note that IANAL and this is only some personal opinion of a layman.

And do not wait until someone does something. You should be the active party to find out. That works best by contacting the original author of that component, tell her what you want to do with it and keep the written allowance you get from her with your records. Especially as you are unsure. And the original author has enough power to allow you things even apart from the public visible license btw..